# Single table inheritance subclasses unknown until super is referenced

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have three classes defined as follows:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :animal_definition_id, :aquarium_id

  belongs_to :animal_definition
  belongs_to :aquarium

  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Fish < Animal
end

class Coral < Animal
end
```

If I fire up a console and type:

```
Coral.all
```

I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Coral
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/gjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@WebDev/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/gjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@WebDev/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/gjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@WebDev/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Now... if I type `Animal.all` it works as expected.  And then `Coral.all` works fine!

Why does Animal need to be referenced before Coral works?  Same behavior, by the way, if I'm doing something other than `all`.  `Coral.class` does the same thing.

I haven't seen this behavior in my actual application, but I fear its a weird bug waiting to happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails loads its models dynamically as they're called. So when you first call `Animal.all` you're telling Rails to go find the `models/animal.rb` file and load it in - your other classes get loaded in at that time too.

If you want to be able to call `Coral` and `Fish` regardless of whether `Animal` has been loaded in or not, just put them in the files `models/coral.rb` and `models/fish.rb`. That should work for you.